# Flash Actions Panel Splitting

Tags: flash, panel, flash-cs6

Simple question (hopefully):
How do you split/copy a panel in Flash CS6? I'm trying to accomplish this so I can easily access my code without needing to scroll. I'm hoping for the same affect as splitting screens on Blender (except with code, not graphics).

Comment: don't think it's possible: might be easier to use a second monitor than to split panels in flash cs6

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. One would think that Adobe would've thought something like this through. It burns so much of my time having to scroll through my code. Perhaps there's some type of Flash CS6 "add on" that enhances Flash user interface?

Comment: You shouldn't use Flash CS6 if you have a lot of code. You should use an IDE like Flash Builder/FDT/FlashDevelop(free/lightweight/awesome/but Windows only)/IntelliJ IDEA/etc. All you need to do is setup linkage/export for actionscript for your symbols in the Library then you can publish your fla document as a .swc which you use in your preffered IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do it is to simply place sections of your code on different layers. I'm so used to doing all my code on one layer that it never crossed my mind. Problem solved. I'd like to thank everyone for helping me out

Comment: If anyone has any other ways around this inconveninence I'm still all ears.